# What program to use for drawing algorithm flowcharts?

Tags: software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good (preferably free), easy to use, attractive flowchart software](https://superuser.com/questions/426591/good-preferably-free-easy-to-use-attractive-flowchart-software)

I need to draw algorithm flowcharts and have already used the program "Dia". It's not bad, but is there something better?

Comment: see also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/19552

Comment: What sort of diagrams are you drawing. Is it the traditional diamond (decision) and rectangle (process) type ones or is it more complex?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Good (preferably free), easy to use, attractive flowchart software](http://superuser.com/questions/426591/good-preferably-free-easy-to-use-attractive-flowchart-software) and [Application to Help Build Diagrams](http://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams).

Answer (score 1):

Two I know of:

- TikZ, if you like LaTeX: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/
- MS Visio, if you like commercial solutions: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visio

Answer (score 0):

[Graphviz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz) and the *dot* language might be the answer to all your troubles, unless it's not. In that case you should use something else.